# How to retrieve app data

Tags: samsung

I have a galaxy j3 emerge and I can't use clipboard on it so I downloaded a clipboard app, "clipboard actions" app. If you swipe a clipboard post it deletes a clipboard entry and I accidently deleted one that I'm trying to retrieve. Is there any way to retrieve deleted app data?